# Get name of object JSON with php

Tags: php, json

How do I get the string (3h) from this JSON object only using "rain" with php (json_decode)?

```
{
    "rain": {
        "3h": 3.5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for getting at the properties of that rain object, which is, in essence, what you want to do:

```
$json = '{
    "rain": {
        "3h": 3.5
    }
}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
$rain = $obj->rain;
$rain_properties = get_object_vars($rain);
// you now have an associative array that lists all keys and values for properties of the object
// you can look at the keys using
$rain_keys = array_keys($rain_properties);
echo $rain_keys[0]; // would give '3h' in this example
// or, you can iterate through the properties
foreach($rain_properties as $key => $value) {
    echo $key; // would give '3h' on first iteration in this example
    echo $value; // would give 3.5 in this example
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$struct = json_decode('{
    "rain": {
        "3h": 3.5
    }
}', true); // get as associative array
array_keys($struct["rain"])[0]; // "3h"
```

Or if you're not on PHP5.4

```
$keys = array_keys($struct["rain"]);
$keys[0]; // "3h";
```

Answer (score 0):

$arr = json_decode('{
    "rain": {
        "3h": 3.5
    }
}', true);

$arr2 = $arr['rain'];

$arr3 = array_keys($arr2);

var_dump($arr3[0]); // string(2) "3h"